# Vectorize get() method in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, methods, vectorization

I'm trying to vectorize the get() method from one column containing dictionaries to another column in the same dataframe. For example, I would like the cities in the address column dictionaries to populate the address.city column.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'address': [{'city': 'Lake Ashley', 'state': 'MN', 'street': '56833 Baker Branch', 'zip': '15884'},
                           {'city': 'Reginaldfurt', 'state': 'MO',
                               'street': '045 Bennett Motorway Suite 404', 'zip': '68916'},
                           {'city': 'East Stephaniefurt', 'state': 'VI', 'street': '908 Matthew Ports Suite 313', 'zip': '15956-9706'}],
               'address.city': [None, None, None],
               'address.street': [None, None, None]})
```

I was trying

```
df['address.city'].apply(df.address.get('city'))
```

but that doesn't work. I figured I was close since `df.address[0].get('city')` does extract the city value for that row. As you can imagine I want to do the same for address.street.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want is below the following.  However, You can parse the `address` column like this

```
df.address.apply(pd.Series).add_prefix('address.')
# or
# pd.DataFrame(df.address.tolist()).add_prefix('address.')

         address.city address.state                  address.street address.zip
0         Lake Ashley            MN              56833 Baker Branch       15884
1        Reginaldfurt            MO  045 Bennett Motorway Suite 404       68916
2  East Stephaniefurt            VI     908 Matthew Ports Suite 313  15956-9706
```

---

This answers your question:

```
df['address.city'] = df.address.apply(lambda d: d['city'])

df

                                             address        address.city address.street
0  {'city': 'Lake Ashley', 'state': 'MN', 'street...         Lake Ashley           None
1  {'city': 'Reginaldfurt', 'state': 'MO', 'stree...        Reginaldfurt           None
2  {'city': 'East Stephaniefurt', 'state': 'VI', ...  East Stephaniefurt           None
```

Comment: Yes, that is ultimately what I'm going for. Bravo! and thank you!